# why is this Vuex state syntax throwing error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

I'm quite new with Vuejs & Vuex, I created a local project just to practice, so I have a file called: employeeList with an Array of objects. I'm trying to pass that same Array as state in Vuex, but is throwing me errors. I assume the syntax is wrong, please tell what would be the correct approach and if the problem is in fact the syntax. Thank you & here's the code :

```
export const employeesModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state : {
        [
            {
            id: 1, 
            name:'Terry Lawrence',
            username:'TerryLaw',
            email: 'TerryLaw@gmail.com',
            address: 'whateverStreet 258',
            checked: checked.value
            },
            {
            id: 2, 
            name:'MartyClFly',
            username:'MartyMac',
            email: 'MartyMac@gmail.com',
            address: 'George Junior 300',
            checked: checked.value
            },
            {
            id: 3, 
            name:'Nancy Pelosi',
            username:'Drunk ho',
            email: 'drunkHo@gmail.com',
            address: 'Velbedere 400',
            checked: checked.value
            }
]
            
    },
```

The actual file is longer, but there's no purpose to add the mutations, actions, etc...

Comment: Your state structure looks wrong, which version of Vuex do you have installed?

Comment: Check the documentation, you should have the state as a function. https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Comment: This is invalid JS, `state : {  [ ... ] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong on your object "state". If you want it to be an object that contains an array, you need to set it a value like so:

```
state: {
  newArray: [...]
}
```

You can't just have an object that contains an array and is not set with a key.